# Poner marca de agua en imágenes

Tags: php, imagen

Las imagenes que aparecen en la descripcion del producto en el siguiente link estan hospedadas en mi servidor. Estas imágenes son *linkeadas/accedidas* desde Mercado Libre.

http://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-638520327-alisado-de-cabellos-con-shock-de-queratina-y-botox-_JM

Necesito que cuando alguien acceda al link antes mencionado y al abrir las imagenes en una nueva ventana del navegador/explorador de internet, se muestre estampada con una marca de agua.

A quien pueda ayudarme, les dejo el código *PHP* y *htaccess* que intento usar:

***htaccess***

```
RewriteEngine On

# No referrer is okay
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [NC]
# Avoid an infinite loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.wm/.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/add-watermark.php/.* [NC]
# Don't watermark it if it's being shown on this site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([^/]*\.)?mercadolibre\.com\.ar($|/.*) [NC]
# Things in the /stuff directory are okay to be hotlinked
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stuff/ [NC]

### Sites to not watermark
# Let's be friendly to search engine image caches
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([^/]*\.)/search\?q=cache\:.*$ [NC]

# Weblog syndications
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([^/]*\.)?bloglines.com($|/) [NC]
# (other whitelisted regular expressions go here - start them with ! to negate them)

# If something gets this far, it's hotlinked and not whitelisted; add the watermark
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]*\.(gif|png|jpg)) /add-watermark.php/$1/$2 [R,L]
```

***add-watermark.php***

```
<?php

@mkdir(".wm", 0777);

$in = preg_replace(['-^/-', '-\.\./-'], '', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
$out = ".wm/$in";

$log = fopen(".wm/log-" . date('Y-m'), 'a');
fwrite($log, date(DATE_W3C) . '|' . $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
       . '|' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\n");
fclose($log);

if (file_exists($in)
    && (!file_exists($out) || filemtime($out) < filemtime($in))) {
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->readImage($in) or die("Couldn't load $in");

    $wm = new Imagick();
    $wm->readImage("watermark.png") or die("Couldn't load $wm");

    $image->compositeImage($wm, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

    @mkdir(dirname($out), 0777, true);
    $image->writeImage($out);
}

header('Location: /' . $out);
?>
```

Comment: A esta pregunta le falta información: ¿Qué es lo que falla? ¿No se pone la marca de agua? ¿Se pone cuando no se debería poner? ¿No se redirecciona correctamente? ¿Recibes algún error?

Comment: Lo que falla es que a veces se pone la marca de agua y otras veces no

Comment: ¿En qué casos se ponen la marca de agua y en qué casos no?¿Cuándo te está fallando?¿Puedes poner ejemplos de URLs en las que funciona y en las que falla? Es importante intentar identificar si es un problema con el `.htaccess` o el PHP porque son dos cosas completamente diferentes, y con la descripción y explicación que das, es imposible saberlo.

Comment: Estimado, a mi me da la impresion que es solo un problema de cache, si la imagen la accediste desde fuera de mercado libre con marca de agua es muy probable que luego la veas con marca de agua en mercado libre, para hacer las pruebas debes presionar CTRL+F5 para forzar la recarga de todos los elementos.

Si este no es el caso, entonces debes dar detalles de las pruebas como:

¿Hay marca de agua intermitente con la misma url?
Si la respuesta es no
Entonces indicar con cuales hay marca y con cuales no.

Comment: Por favor alguna ayuda?

Comment: Por favor, proporciona casos de uso en tu pregunta. Al menos un link de imagen que se genere correctamente y otro de una imagen que no se genere correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

No hace mucho tiempo lo hice, creo que con tu código (con todo respeto) te estas complicando, me base en la documentación de PHP. Te anexo el ejemplo.

```
<?php
// Cargar la estampa y la foto para aplicarle la marca de agua
$estampa = imagecreatefrompng('estampa.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('foto.jpeg');

// Establecer los márgenes para la estampa y obtener el alto/ancho de la imagen de la estampa
$margen_dcho = 10;
$margen_inf = 10;
$sx = imagesx($estampa);
$sy = imagesy($estampa);

// Copiar la imagen de la estampa sobre nuestra foto usando los índices de márgen y el
// ancho de la foto para calcular la posición de la estampa. 
imagecopy($im, $estampa, imagesx($im) - $sx - $margen_dcho, imagesy($im) - $sy - $margen_inf, 0, 0, imagesx($estampa), imagesy($estampa));

// Imprimir y liberar memoria
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Así queda el resultado, no se si te sirva. Saludos.
[image: Así es el resultado]